# I'm trying to install a extension that is no longer available on the marketplace

Tags: vscode-extensions

Extension: [IBM Blockchain Platform](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/blockchain?topic=blockchain-develop-vscode)

I have taken the extension files from a friend who has it installed in his machinne, I have tried on ubuntu and windows both, I can't get VsCode to pick up the extension.

Commands i have tried:

```
sudo cp -R ./ibmblockchain.ibm-blockchain-platform-2.0.8 ~/.vscode/extensions/
```

Comment: It's retired, so leave it behind if you can. Otherwise, you can learn from its code and support yourself, https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/blockchain-vscode-extension